# Python: type inheritance without overloading method with the same name?

Tags: python-3.x, oop

is it possible to achieve type inheritance without overwriting class methods? Take for example this code:

```
class Parent:
    def special_method(self, name):
        print("hello, {}!".format(name))

class Child:
    def __init__(self, injected_parent):
        self.parent = injected_parent

    def special_method(self):
        self.parent.special_method("Homer Simpson")



parent = Parent()
child = Child(parent)

child.special_method()
# hello, Homer Simpson!
```

Works as expected, but I want the type of `child` to be `Parent` and not `Child`:

```
print(type(child))
<class '__main__.Child'>
```

One way I've seen it done is to extend `Child` with:

```
class Child:
    def __init__(self, injected_parent):
        self.parent = injected_parent
        self.__class__ = Parent
...
```

However, then `child`'s `special_method` gets overwritten:

```
parent = Parent()
child = Child(parent)

child.special_method()
# TypeError: special_method() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'
```

Any way to make `child` have type `Parent` without side-effects?

Comment: Why would you want such a thing? I see no point to OOP inheritance if you want a subclass to exclusively have the type of its superclass. If you make `Child` inherit from`Parent`, then `Child` is still an instance of `Parent`, but if you want it to _be_ a `Parent` then what exactly is the point of inheriting?

Comment: If all you want is to be able to check if a `Child` is a `Parent` then use `isinstance` rather than `type` like this: `isinstance(child, Parent)` which will return `True` if you make your `Child` class inherit from `Parent`

Comment: `Child` is in no sense a child of `Parent`. You are using *composition* but then speaking the language of inheritance. This is confused. Note, `self.__class__ = Parent` isn't "extending", it's a *very hacky* way to *change the type* of the object.

Comment: The point is that I want `Child` to have `Parent`'s functionality, which then gets built onto by `Child`'s methods. So view `Parent` as a sort of a base class which gets extended.

Comment: Then you should define your class like `class Child(Parent):` so that it inherits from `Parent`. In this case, an instance of `Child` will also be an instance of `Parent` and you can also define your overloaded `special_method`

Comment: Yes, `special_method` gets overloaded, which means that I cannot use `Parent`'s `special_method` anymore, unless I change some names. Class composition allows me to use both methods without any name changes.

Comment: You need to choose whether you are going to go with inheritance or composition. The type system is the way it is. Note, "which means that I cannot use Parent's special_method anymore, unless I change some names." is not correct. You can *directly* call `Parent.method_name(self, a, b)` etc, or use `super().method_name(a, b)`.

Comment: That's not true. You can use the `super` keyword to refer to the parent class's method: `super().special_method()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like what you want to do is just regular inheritance, but as @juanpa.arrivillaga pointed out, you are using composition instead. What you are trying to do by changing the `__class__` *and* overloading a method will not work. Here is an example using inheritance which will allow you to overload the method while still having access to the original method and to have `child` be an instance of `parent` which seems to meet your requirements:

```
class Parent:
    def special_method(self, name):
        print("hello, {}!".format(name))

class Child(Parent):
    def special_method(self):
        super().special_method("Homer Simpson")

child = Child()
```

Now, `child` will still have a *type* of `Child`, but with classes what you want to be checking instead is whether it is an *instance* of the superclass using `isinstance`:

```
>>> child.special_method()
hello, Homer Simpson!

>>> type(child)
<class '__main__.Child'>

>>> isinstance(child, Parent)
True
```